# salesforce1 image upload on android

Tags: salesforce1-app

I added the html tag for bring up the file upload on Salesforce1. It works on the iphone but it doesn't work on the android phone ( Samsung Note 4 comes with Android 4.4.2 )
Is there anything missing or SF1 file upload doesn't work on the android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google intentionally removed the functionality to open a file chooser from webviews in Android 4.4 (chromium 30 based webviews), as it wasn't a public API.  This impacts Cordova/Phonegap which Salesforce1 is built on top of.

According to [this Android issue tracker thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220) it should be fixed in Android 4.4.3 (chromium 33 based webviews), though this appears to be a partial fix as some people appear to be still experiencing problems with that and 4.4.4.

There's some more detail from the Cordova perspective [on their bug reporting system.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5294)

Comment: Thanks. I hope to see it working on newer version. By the way salesforce1 is built on top of aura not phonegap. http://jessealtman.com/2013/12/introduction-to-aura/

Comment: Not so - Aura isn't a mobile application container, its a user interface framework.  Salesforce1 is most definitely built on the mobile SDK which is in turn built on phonegap/cordova. Aura provides the user interface components.

Comment: Here is really good question on the subject as well: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22655/how-are-salesforce1-and-aura-related